# Reverse WooCommerce Shipping Address Form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently the checkout page of woocommerce has a tickbox that says are you shipping to a different address. When ticked it displays a form.

I would like to reverse this. I want the shipping form to display by default. I have changed the label to say "shipping address the same as billing address?". When the box is ticked the form should be hidden.

Comment: please show what you tried

Comment: please clarify your question